# Updating array element in a collection in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to find and update an element within an array in a mongodb collection in a meteor app.

Every element in the array is an object that has an "_id" attribute, so I'm using mongo's '$' pointer:

```
Collection.update({things._id: currentThingId},{$set: {things.$.value: aGivenValue}});
```

However, it keeps throwing me an "Unexpected ." exception, pointing to the line where I use "things**.**_id". I followed mongodb documentation, so any chance meteor has some limitatiob with this mongo functionality?

Comment: You forgot the quotes around "things._id" and co. It has to look like `{'things._id' : currentThingId}`. You can't use `.` in a property name outside a string.

Comment: You right. I tried to enclose with "" before asking here, but did forgot the things.$.value. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enclose the field with quotes when using the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)** to access an element of an array by the zero-based index position, bearing in mind that the [**positional `$`** **operator**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) limits the contents of an array from the query results to contain only the first element matching the query document. Thus your final update query should look like:

```
Collection.update({"things._id": currentThingId},{$set: {"things.$.value": aGivenValue}});
```

Comment: Thank you, I did enclose it but forgot to enclose the things.$.value.

Answer (score 4):

If every element in your array is an object with an "_id" attribute, why don't you use 

`Collection.update({_id: currentThingId},{$set:{fieldToSet: aGivenValue}});`

where fieldToSet is the name of the attribute you want to set aGivenValue to.

Comment: I didn't bump into this solution when looking for it, but it does looks interesting. I'll check it out, many thanks!